# American to British English: down/mid/up-towns?

Tags: word-usage, transatlantic-differences

How do you convert down/mid/up towns to British English?

- Core (less than 2 km<sup>2</sup>) part of city; usually the financial district

  - American: downtown + *city name*
  - British: *city name* + city centre
- Urban (between city centre and suburb)

  - American: midtown + *city name*
  - British: *city name* + urban area
- Outer part of city; zone for housing complexes and parks

  - American: uptown + *city name*
  - British: suburban + *city name*

Comment: Are you speaking generally, or in a scienfic context.  Could you give some examples of the sentences that you want to say.

Comment: See this earlier question : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136933/difference-between-uptown-downtown-and-midtown

Comment: @James K Speaking generally. I am finding equivalent words between American and British English such as backpack/rucksack, line/queue, apartment/flat.